# Redmine Direct login after Keycloak Integration

Tags: plugins, single-sign-on, keycloak, openid, redmine

I have integrated Keycloak with Redmine. Now users can login via Keycloak SSO. But, I have tried to login Redmine direct login using this URL ([www.myredminedomain.com/login?local_login=true](http://www.myredminedomain.com/login?local_login=true)).

The redmine login page is appeared but says invalid username and password. But I can use those credential to login to redmine via keycloak SSO perfectly. I'm using this plugin "redmine_openid_connect" Any help on this please?

I tried to changed the password from myaccount in redmine but it doesn't work. Crate a new user in keycloak and tried it but not working.